# Wordpress Redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to create a series of redirect (without a plugin) for a few of my taxonomies.

Essentially I want all sitedomain.com/taxonomy1/term and sitedomain.com/taxonomy2/term to point to sitedomain.com/page?taxonomy1=term and sitedomain.com/page?taxonomy2=term repsectively.

I have a page using URL queries so I'd rather direct users there than show a 'taxonomy' page.

I assume that I can do this with htaccess or Wordpress' redirect rules but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use .htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 /taxonomy1/term /page?taxonomy1=term
Redirect 301 /taxonomy2/term /page?taxonomy2=term
```

You can also use `RedirectMatch`, or a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress doesn't auto generate an archive of terms.

for `sitedomain.com/taxonomy1/term` to work, what you will need to do is create a template page called `taxonomy1-term.php`.

Also make sure wordpress can write (permissions) to your .htaccess file under the permalinks tab within the admin section.

Comment: But that means if someone goes to sitedomain.com/taxonomy1/term it will use the most applicable archive page - which I don't want. I want users to be redirected to an entirely different page.

Comment: You would like one page i.e. 'page.php' to handle all of your taxonomy requests?

Comment: I have a page set up for dealing with URL queries. 

All I want to do is redirect users from a default taxonomy page to my page with URL queries.

Comment: if wordpress cannot find a template for taxonomies, it will headover to the index.php. Here you can to a check to see what was within the query. If taxonomies and terms are set then use header(); to redirect to that page with your URL queries. Let me know if I am getting you right

Comment: I'm not sure. Can't I just redirect any page at /taxonomy/ to a new URL?

Comment: Well yeah. The above suggestion is that you catch the arguments at index.php and then forward them on to a new URL

Answer (score 0):

If you need a redirect function that works anywhere on the page without any header redirection issues add this function to your `functions.php`:

```
function once_no_wp_redirect ( $page_id, $form_id ) { 
echo '<form method="post" id="' . $form_id . '" style="display: none;" action="'. get_permalink ( $page_id ) .'">
<input type="submit" />
</form>';
echo '<script>document.getElementById("' . $form_id . '").submit();</script>';
}
```

Instead of `wp_redirect()` use `once_no_wp_redirect()`.

Also, you can pass variables to your destination page by adding more input fields to the form. Example: automatically login users after successful registration form submission using `wp_login_url()` as a redirect url.

Feel free to comment if you any improvements.